# Maximum call stack size exceeded in react with pdf-lib library

Tags: reactjs, pdflib

I want to insert the image inside the existing pdf. So i use the pdf-lib libary in react.When i use this code i got maximum call stack size exceeded error in mobile. how to solve this. Anyone can help with this?

```
 const createpdf1 = async (signurl) => {
 try {

 const pdfData = new Uint8Array(await fetch(samplePdf).then((response) => 
 response.arrayBuffer()));


 const imageBlob = await fetch(ur).then((response) => response.arrayBuffer());


 const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfData);


 const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
 const fifthpage = pages[5]; 


 const image = await pdfDoc.embedPng(imageBlob);
 const { width, height } = image.scale(0.2); // Adjust the scale as needed


 fifthpage.drawImage(image, {
  x: 500, // Adjust the X and Y coordinates as needed
  y: 180,
  width,
  height,
  opacity: 1,
 });

 const modifiedPdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();


 const modifiedPdfDataUri = `data:application/pdf;base64,${btoa(
  String.fromCharCode(...modifiedPdfBytes)
 )}`;


setPdfDataUri(modifiedPdfDataUri)
return modifiedPdfDataUri;
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error loading or manipulating the PDF:', error);
throw error;
}
};
```

Comment: It's possible that the issue might be related to memory consumption, especially on mobile devices where resources are more limited.